# Range of $\tan^{-1} (2x)$?

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry

This is a doubt I got in the following question: Set of all values of x so 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}
    \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{4\tan^{-1} (2x)}{\pi}}\right)^2n
$$ is non zero and finite, n is a natural number . Answer is [-1/2,1/2].

The answer says $4\tan^{-1} (2x)/\pi$ has range -1 to 1 . How is this possible when range of $\tan^{-1} x$ is $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$?

Comment: $(4/\pi) \arctan(2x)$ has a range of $[-2,2]$ so I'm not sure where the answer is getting that from ...

Comment: See this [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); for example, type \tan^{-1}

Comment: Your limit is $\frac{n}{9}$